# How can I add an animation on my HTML form when submit input is clicked and the input is empty on Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, frameworks

Basically, I'm coding a Javascript code that validate if a form is empty, so if one input is empty, it add an animation from Animate.css library. And if two inputs are empty, both will make the shake animation, if the whole form is empty, it will shake.

I've tried a global function with conditions that add a class and it doesn't work.

This is my form:

```
<form action="" id="form">
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input
    type="text"
    placeholder="Name"
    id="name"
    minlength="3"
    required
  />
  <br />
  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input type="email" placeholder="Emai" id="email" required />
  <br />
  <label for="subject">Subject</label>
  <input
    type="text"
    placeholder="Subject"
    id="subject"
    minlength="3"
    required
  />
  <br />
  <label for="message">Message</label>
  <textarea
    name="message"
    id="message"
    minlength="5"
    placeholder="Message"
    required
    style="resize: none; height: 200px"
  ></textarea>
  <br />
  <button type="submit" class="paper-btn" id="submit">
    Send message
  </button>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
(function () {
  var form = document.getElementById("form"),
    name = form.name,
    email = form.email,
    subject = form.subject;
  message = form.message;

  function validateName(e) {
    if (name.value == "" || name.value == null) {
      form.classList.add("animate__animated");
      name.classList.add("animate__shakeX");
      e.preventDefaul();
    } else {
      console.log("error");
    }
  }
  function validateEmail(e) {
    if (email.value == "" || email.value == null) {
      email.classList.add("animate__animated");
      email.classList.add("animate__shakeX");
      e.preventDefaul();
    }
  }

  function validateSubject(e) {
    if (subject.value == "" || subject.value == null) {
      subject.classList.add("animate__animated");
      subject.classList.add("animate__shakeX");
      e.preventDefaul();
    }
  }

  function validateMessage(e) {
    if (subject.value == "" || subject.value == null) {
      message.classList.add("animate__animated");
      message.classList.add("animate__shakeX");
      e.preventDefaul();
    }
  }

  function validateForm(e) {
    validateName(e);
    validateEmail(e);
    validateSubject(e);
    validateMessage(e);
  }
  form.addEventListener("submit", validateForm);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to invoke the function. ValidateForm isn't being called

```
   (function() {
      var name = document.getElementById("name");
    
      if (name.value == "" || name.value == null) {
        name.classList.add("animate__animated");
        name.classList.add("animate__shakeX"); 
      }
   })();
```

Comment: Doesn't work...

Comment: I also dont think you can add multiple classes in one add try
name.classList.add("animate__animated");
name.classList.add("animate__shakeX");

Comment: because it cant have spaces

Comment: You mean, class spaces? I deleted it and it doesn't work either.

Comment: I tested using just name.classList.add("animate__animated"); for example works and adds the class

Comment: Does it execute the animation?

Comment: I tried and it does, but not when I click the animation:(

Comment: I don't have the code to do the animation, but adding the class was the issue right?

Comment: Yeah, with that code, it adds the class that execute the animation, but now I want it for every input and it executes when people click on submit and something is empty. I updated the question